# set height to video in thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

i have 2 thumbnail. 
1 for image, the other for video.
i set the height for image and video
the img works fine with height but the video is not.
the fact, the video go to bottom like i input margin-bottom if i set height.
how to make the video height is same like image height. in desktop or mobile guys?

my code

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="thumbnail-img">
                  <img src="img/3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                  <h5>how to make like</h5>
                    <a href="#" class="uppercase bold">recipe</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>   

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="thumbnail-img">
                      <video id="video1" class="embed-responsive-item">
                          <source src="video/inspiration-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                      </video>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary play" onclick="playPause()"><li class="fa fa-play"></li></button> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h5 class="h5-big">HOW TO </h5>
                        <a href="detil.html" class="uppercase bold">recipe</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

css
 .thumbnail-img img, .thumbnail-img video{
width: 100%;
height: 295px;
object-fit: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you need thumbnail for a video. If so, then you can use video tag property `poster`. In that case you don't need to simulate thumbnail, you are able make it the same size as video. Just look at my demo.

```css
video {
  width: 400px;
  object-fit: initial;
}
```

```html
<video controls  poster="http://s1.oboiki.net/uploads/images/previews/2015/10/fa9a91b41080fc3589ba7d6d66cf0c94/koshaka-a-lya-sova_550x340.jpg">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: 295px;
object-fit: initial;
```

Answer (score 0):

i fix this bug. it just need this code

```
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9 {
width: 100%;
height: inherit;
max-height: 295px;
object-fit: initial;

}
```